# how to increase websocket speed for receiving data

Tags: opencv, websocket

what I am trying to do is get every frame of a video and then convert it into base64 ad then send and receive through websocket  but what happening is as i receive base64 through websocket , it is very slow. like I want to take base64 and put it in img tag by changing it src so that it look like a video but due to very slow speed of receiving data it don't look like a video. What I want is recive base64 with such speed that img changes continuously making it look like a proper video.

i am new to this websocket if their are any error then please mention that also

here is my code:

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>OpenCV.js</title>
 <style>
     /* display loading gif and hide webpage */
   .modal {
       display:    none;
       position:   fixed;
       z-index:    1000;
       top:        0;
       left:       0;
       height:     100%;
       width:      100%;
       background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8)
                   url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif')
                   50% 50%
                   no-repeat;
   }

   /* prevent scrollbar from display during load */
   body.loading {
       overflow: hidden;
   }

   /* display the modal when loading class is added to body */
   body.loading .modal {
       display: block;
   }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

   <div>
       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="0" border="0">
       <tbody><tr>
           <td>
               <video id="videoInput" width="320" height="240"></video>
           </td>
           <td>
               <canvas id="canvasOutput" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
           </td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <div class="caption">videoInput</div>
           </td>
           <td>
               <div class="caption">canvasOutput</div>
           </td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody></table>
   </div>
   <img id="imageSrc2" alt="No Image" name="fileToUpload" />
   <button id="submit" type="button">Send</button>
   <img id="imageSrc3" alt="No Image" name="fileToUpload" />
  <canvas id="base64canvasOutput" width="320" height="240"></canvas>


   <script type="text/javascript">
     document.body.classList.add('loading');
   </script>

   <script async src= "https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/opencv.js" onload="onOpenCvReady();" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function onOpenCvReady() {
           document.body.classList.remove('loading');
           let video = document.getElementById("videoInput"); // video is the id of video tag
           navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
               .then(function(stream) {
                   video.srcObject = stream;
                   video.play();
               })
               .catch(function(err) {
                   console.log("An error occurred! " + err);
               });


           let src = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
           let dst = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC1);
           let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);
           let imgElement = document.getElementById('imageSrc2');
           let canvasOutput = document.getElementById('canvasOutput');
           let imageSrc2 = document.getElementById('imageSrc2');

           const FPS = 30;
           function processVideo() {

               let begin = Date.now();
               cap.read(src);
               hsv = cv.cvtColor(src, dst, cv.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
               cv.imshow("canvasOutput", dst);
               // schedule next one.

               var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasOutput');
               var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
               imgElement.src = dataURL;

               sendbase64(dataURL);

               let delay = 1000/FPS - (Date.now() - begin);
               setTimeout(processVideo, delay);

           }


           function sendbase64(dataURL){

               const messageInputDom = dataURL;
               const message = messageInputDom;
               chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                   'message': message
               }));
               messageInputDom.value = '';
           }


           // schedule first one.
           setTimeout(processVideo, 0);
       }

       const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
           'ws://'
           + window.location.host
           + '/ws/example/send/'
       );

       chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
           const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
           document.querySelector('#imageSrc3').src = (data.message);
           
       };

       chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
           console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
       };


       document.querySelector('#imageSrc2').focus();
       document.getElementById('imageSrc2').onchange = function() {
               document.querySelector('#submit').click();
               console.log("run");
       };

   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and consumers.py:

```
import asyncio
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer



class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
   async def connect(self):
       await self.accept()

   async def disconnect(self, close_code):
       # Leave room group
       pass

   # Receive message from WebSocket
   async def receive(self, text_data):
       text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
       message = text_data_json['message']
       # Send message to room group
       await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
               'message': message
           }))


   # Receive message from room group
   async def chat_message(self, event):
       message = event['message']

       # Send message to WebSocket
       await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
           'message': message
       }))
```

any correction or suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: Does anything change if you remove the `setTimeout(processVideo, delay)` ?

Comment: @JohnZwinck on doing this all the video stops except video in video tag

Comment: Ah, uncompressed, base64 encoded video.  Let's do some math. You seem to set canvas to size 320x240, so I'll assume that's the frame size, I see `FPS=30` there, and I'll assume RGB. Tiny, right? Well... that's `320 * 240 * 3 = 230400` bytes per frame. Base64 uses 4 symbols to encode 3 bytes -- `230400 * 4/3 = 307200` bytes per encoded frame. This gives us `307200 * 30 = 9216000` bytes per second, (or about `8.8 MiB/s`). Do you have 70 mbit/s sustained bandwidth available for this?

Comment: @DanMašek ah ... no i don't think but i am running this in local server so is bandwidth important? just asking i don't know much about this